# Recently Viewed products issue in Magento V2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1, products

Today I configured the **Recently Viewed products** in my local website, It is showing **When Customer Login** in `front store` otherwise it's not showing.

Is it **Customer Session** based or It will shown every Customer (Guest, General..etc)?

[image]

I want to show **Recently Viewed products** to **everyone** how can I configure this?

Any help?

Comment: where you have addred recently viewed product widget ? where you want to show it ?

Comment: @ManthanDave I want to show `category List pages`, `My account pages`, `Home Page` and `Shopping Cart Page`.

Comment: then go to that cms block and add recently viewed product widget over there .. it will show for all users

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes I have created Block with widget. Now how can I display this block on sidebar of above listed pages?

Comment: For few pages you can add from backend and for few pages you need to override template and need to add widget in that paritcular overrided template

Answer (score 1):

**Lets take an example for homepage**. if you want to show "Recently Viewed Products" on your homepage **follow below steps** :

1. Login to your admin panel
2. Click on content - > Blocks - > Find Homepage Block
3. Click on Homepage Block and edit then toggle show/hide editor , You
   will see insert widget option there
4. Click on insert widget select "Recently Viewed Products" from
   dropdown , add number of product to display (ex - 5)
5. Select template from dropdown then click on insert widget
6. Click on save Block then go to the front side on homepage . View any
   product
7. Back to the homepage you will see "Recently Viewed Product" over
   there.

Comment: I have followed your steps, still not showing `{{widget type="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" page_size="3" template="widget/viewed/column/viewed_default_list.phtml"}}`

Comment: @magentotwo have you added it on homepage? its working fine for me by following above steps

Comment: If i extend this block, Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed, It show constructor compatibility error

Answer (score 0):

Recently viewed products shows visited products by one single visitor. Yes, it is bind by each visitor. If you made it work for all users without changing any code, most likely it is false. The block you say you added on homepage may be full page cached and homepage may look the same for all users.

I guess you could try to make a plugin on function
`Magento\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Report\Product\Viewed::getItemsCollection()`
This function has this:

```
if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
  $this->_collection->setCustomerId($this->getCustomerId());
}
```

You could try to setCustomerId(null) on recently viewed block.

Or create your block and inherit from `Magento\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Report\Product\Viewed` class or just from class `Magento\Reports\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`.

If your block gets cached in full page cache type, than it's another issue but can be done.

Comment: Yes, I think so, I will get back after I tried.